# Android ftp4j - remote file size doesn't match local file size after upload success

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp4j

I got a weird bug here. In order to upload file to my ftp server I imported ftp4j package in my android app. Problem is whenever the upload is complete the uploaded file size change, I checked the file content it does not match the original content as well. Also I don't think this is caused by internet problem accidentally, as I tested my code for three times and I got the same results, the original file size is 154266 in bytes and the remote size became 201673 bytes every time the upload completed.

Here is part of my code.

```
client = new FTPClient();
client.upload(file, new MyTransferListener(file));

public class MyTransferListener implements FTPDataTransferListener {
    private File file;
    private String filename;

    public MyTransferListener(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        filename = file.getName();
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void completed() {
        try {
                file.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it a text file ? If so how many lines? Check newfilesize == (oldfilesize + numberoflines) ?

Comment: Is it a valid file on the server? You only told about a different size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are uploading in text mode. Try to put your client in binary transfer mode first.